# How do I connect up a ceiling rose in a 2-way switch circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I removed a ceiling rose and forgot to at least take an image or draw the wiring before replacing it.

It is part of a 2 way switch (the other switch is upstairs).  However, the wiring colours are confusing me as I'm not sure what the yellow is for.  If it's earth, why is there already a copper wire in the cable to the left?

[image]

Comment: Was there a junction box for these? Wires should be terminated in a rated [junction box](http://homerepair.about.com/od/electricalrepair/ss/elec_box_ltg.htm) and connected with [box connectors](http://i.imgur.com/eR5UMYW.png)

Comment: There are not enough wires if the travelers pass through here, yet there are too many wires if they don't. The number makes sense for a light and power carried on elsewhere, but the colors don't make sense for that scenario. To make sense of this, we'll need to see how the two switches are connected up as well. FYI, they are called 3-way switches even though there are only two of them and each one only has two possible positions. Each switch does have 3 terminals however.

Comment: Just to clarify one thing: In the UK, they call circuits with 2 switches "2-way" while in North America we call them "3-way" (because of 3 terminals, I guess). I am guessing this is a UK-focused questions since [ceiling rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_rose) is also a UK/Australian thing (I know because I had to look it up to see if it was a real term. :) ). So for North Americans: this is for a 3-way circuit.

Comment: This is a UK circuit.  When I tested, the long red & black wires had a constant circuit regardless of whether the switch was on or off.  Does this help? I'm trying to compare with this circuit here: http://www.ceilingrosewiring.co.uk/ceiling-rose-wiring-with-two-way-switching-older-cable-colours/

Comment: There is a good post here regarding the different terminology used in the [US and UK regarding 2 and 3 way switching](http://www.lightwiring.co.uk/lighting-circuit-components/light-switches/multiway-switching-and-switches-uk-and-us-terminology/)